# While binding edit icon using formatter ,onclick event not triggered in angular8 (Tabulator)

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, angular8, tabulator

[![enter image description here][1]][1][![enter image description here][2]][2]Question :While binding edit icon with onclick event not triggered that function in angular8

Please find my below code .Thanks in advance While binding edit icon using formatter ,onclick event not triggered in angular8 (Tabulator)

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges, Output } from '@angular/core';
import Tabulator from 'tabulator-tables';
    
@component({
    selector: 'app-tabulator',
    templateUrl: './tabulator.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./tabulator.component.scss']
})

export class TabulatorComponent implements OnChanges {
    
    @input() tableData: any[] = [
        {name:"Oli Bob", location:"name"},
        {name:"Mary May", location:"gender"},
    ];

    @input() columnNames: any[] = [
        { title:"Name", field:"name",width:450},
        {title:"Gender", field:"gender",width:450,formatter:this.editClicked}
    ];
    
    @input() height: string = '311px';
    // list properties you want to set per implementation here...
    
    tab = document.createElement('div');
    
    constructor() {
    }

    editClicked(){
        return "< button onclick='clickMe()' >Edit< / button >";
    }

    //this method not called
    clickMe(){
        alert("inside click me")
    }
    
    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
        this.drawTable();
    }

    ngOnInit(){
        this.functiontest();
        this.drawTable();
    }

    public drawTable(): void {
        //alert()
        new Tabulator(this.tab, {
            data: this.tableData,
            reactiveData:true, //enable data reactivity
            columns: this.columnNames,
            layout: 'fitData',
            height: this.height
        });

        document.getElementById('my-tabular-table').appendChild(this.tab);
    }
}


[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1QZ2.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSMet.gif
```

Answer (score 1):

To bind to a DOM event, surround the DOM event name in parentheses and assign a quoted template statement to it.

Example

```
<!-- for onclick -->
<button (click)="onClickMe()">Click me!</button>

<!-- for onkeyup -->
<input (keyup)="onKey($event)">
```

[Sample live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jw44nl?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)

In you code use (click)='clickMe()' inside editClicked method

```
editClicked(){
    return "<button (click)='clickMe()' >Edit</button>";
}
```

Reference

[Angular - User Input](https://angular.io/guide/user-input)

**Specific to your code.**

It won't work. Since you're using Tabulator package. But you could use their callbacks.

Provide implementation for cellClick function.

[Tabulator - table callback documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.5/callbacks#table)

Comment: Thanks For your reply .. When i am using like you said , it can't trigger clickme() function

Comment: Probably there is another issue. Check the console, If any error is there share them.

Comment: I have worked what you said, Please refer the attached gif file in question

Comment: One more thing, open console, reload the application and navigate to that page. Check any errors are there..

Comment: No errors in console i have attached the image in question please check.

Comment: This is my HTML code < div id = " my-tabular-table " > < / div >

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is not working is because the formatter is called after react has built the DOM so you need to treat it as vanilla JS, it will not parse the react props out of the tag.

```
var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
btn.innerHTML = "Click me!";

btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    clickMe();
});
```